# SendAsync with CancellationToken

Tags: c#

I was looking through the code of my old project and I found this:

```
private async void send(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    //...
}
```

I was wondering what would happen when it's cancelled?

What would be in the response?

Do I need to call `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` after that, or it will raise an exception itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering what would happen when it's cancelled?

The [standard pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx) is to cancel the returned task. This will cause your `await` to raise an `OperationCanceledException`.

> What would be in the response?

There would be no response object, since the exception is thrown before that point.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call it like this

```
...
cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
...
```

Then it will throw an exception of the type OperationCanceledException when you will request cancellation.